# Difference between dropping years and "if Year > 2005"

Tags: stata

I have a dataset of the top management teams of US banks from 2005 - 2015.
Now I want to generate a change-variable if a TMT composition changed between 2006 and 2009.

So first I used:

```
drop if Year > 2009
drop if Year < 2006
by id (id), sort: gen changed = (DirectorID[1] != DirectorID[_N])
```

and afterwards I used

```
by id (id), sort: gen changed = (DirectorID[1] != DirectorID[_N]) if Year < 2010 & Year > 2005
```

However there is a difference in output between two variables:
247 cases of "No change" and 853 cases of "Change" in the first and 116 cases of "No change" and the rest as "Changed" in the second variable

Could anyone clarify what the differences between these two commands are in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons you may be seeing a different count of changes to the dataset. The data is most likely sorted differently for these two calls. The `(id)` parts have no effect here because you are already sorting by `id`. What you likely want to do is residually sort by year. So, `bysort id (Year)` - this way the dataset will be in the same order for each command you type. In the second command, the `if` clause is going to set the variable `changed` to missing for observations outside of the year range, but those observations are still being included in the calculation. You could create a new variable to flag the years of interest, and then add that new variable to the `bysort` call.

Lastly, you need to decide whether you only want to look at changes year-over-year (the value of the `changed` could vary by year within `id`), or have the value of `changed` reflect whether there were any changes in `DirectorID` over the entire time frame of interest (the value of `changed` would be constant within `id`).

Comment: In the second command, the if clause is going to set the variable [changed] to missing for observations outside of the year range, but those observations are still being included in the calculation. 

Now I would like to keep the variable equal for the other years as well (i.e. if it [changed] between 2006-2009 I want the variable to also show the fact that it changed on the years 2005 and 2010-2015).
How would I create that variable? As the changed command I used now only gives missing data on these years.

Comment: Try: `gen interest = inrange(year, 2006,2009)`. Then, `bysort id interest (DirectorID) : gen temp = DirectorID[1] != DirectorID[_N]`. Then, discard the calculation for the by-group that is not of interest: `replace temp = . if interest==0`. Then, aggregate that value across all observations for the `id` with `bysort id : egen changed = max(temp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a toy example illustrating the difference. Essentially, when you drop the data, the last and the first observation *could* be the same, but in general you will have less data to compare the first and last observation since much of the data will be gone. When you use `if`, then the data is still there, even though the calculation is restricted to the middle observation by the `if`:

```
. clear

. input id year director_id

            id       year  directo~d
  1. 1 2016 10
  2. 1 2017 20
  3. 1 2018 30
  4. end

. 
. bys id (year): gen changed = (director_id[1] != director_id[_N]) if year < 2018 & year > 2016
(2 missing values generated)

. list, clean noobs

    id   year   direct~d   changed  
     1   2016         10         .  
     1   2017         20         1  
     1   2018         30         .  

. 
. drop if inlist(year, 2016,2018) 
(2 observations deleted)

. bys id (year): gen changed2 = (director_id[1] != director_id[_N]) if year < 2018 & year > 2016

. list, clean noobs

    id   year   direct~d   changed   changed2  
     1   2017         20         1          0
```

I added a sort by year since that seems in the spirit of your exercise.